# Remove previous force from Rigidbody before adding new force

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm having trouble with applying relative-force to a pooled object.

I have an object-pool that has all my bullets ready for re-use. The bullets are disabled while not in use.

when a player shoots his weapon, a bullet is pulled from the objectpool and the following is done on the bullet, in this order:

- SetActive(true)
- transform.position = bulletSpawnPosition
- transform.rotation = rotation of the gun/barrel
- RigidBody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * speed, ForceMode.Impulse)

This works correct for just one player. When I have another player who also pulls bullets from the objectpool, the bullet seems to keep the rotation of the previous player, so the force is added in the wrong direction.

One thing that I can/could do, is wait for the next frame, between setting the rotation and applying the relative-force, but that feels wrong.
Am i missing something? The code below is slightly modified, but narrows down to what's happening.

```
function Shoot() {
    GameObject poolObject = GetObjectFromPool();
    poolObject.SetActive(true);
    poolObject.transform.position = transform.position;
    poolObject .transform.rotation = transform.rotation;

    if (poolObject != null)
    {
        //add force
        Rigidbody rBody = poolObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rBody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * ProjectileSpeed.Value, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: see the answer below, i did that, and had nothing to do with this problem. I reset the velocity and angularVelocity when the bullet is disabled and marked for re-use. The code shows the use of the bullet, not the resetting. setting a new position and rotation is not something i want to do on reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, it has to do with calling SetActive before setting the position and rotation:

this causes issues:

```
 poolObject.SetActive(true);
 poolObject.transform.position = transform.position;
 poolObject .transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
```

while this works:

```
  poolObject.transform.position = transform.position;
  poolObject .transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
  poolObject.SetActive(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Always reset items from a pool before using them again. Have a function for each type of Object in a pool that you can easily call to reset them. Since the bullet has a `Rigidbody` attached to it and is still moving when you take it from the pool, simply reset the `velocity` and the `angularVelocity` too just in-case it is still rotating. You do that by setting them to `Vector3(0, 0, 0);`. The `Vector3.zero` property is a shortcut for `new Vector3(0, 0, 0);` and should be used here.

This should do it:

```
public void resetPool(Rigidbody rg)
{
    rg.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    rg.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
}
```

Comment: I am doing that. It's really the rotation that isn't updated when adding the relativeForce. The first bullet i use has this issue straight away, so there are no forces working on it. When i have my gun rotated 90 degrees, the first bullet shoots wrong, when i use that bullet again (without rotating) it fires correct.

Comment: When the bullet is disabled, it resets the velocity and angularVelocity, and disables. When it is used again, it sets the position and rotation needed at that time.

Comment: ok, i found the problem, i should call setActive AFTER i set the rotation and position, instead of before

Comment: Thanks for your response, it made me re-read everything and found the possible issue when setting the pooled object active again. Moved it around a bit and got results. Even though it was not the answer, still managed to get me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

For setting rigidbody' s velocity to zero, at least one fixedupdate must be passed. So you have to wait for fixedupdate to handle pyhsic. Before disabling and pooling object use a coroutine, first set velocity to zero and waitforfixedupdate. When the object-pooling is in the hand, code below may help:

//Use below line where you want to disable the obj.

```
 StartCoroutine(ResetRigidbodyAndDisable());
```

//and the coroutine below

```
  IEnumerator ResetRigidbodyAndDisable()
        {
            if (rb != null)
            {            
                rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
                rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
            }
            else
            {
                rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
                rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
            }     
            
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
```